# Exchange 2007 - Forward outbound mail to external SMTP server?

Tags: smtp, exchange-2007

How do I configure Exchange Server 2007 to send outbound email thru an external SMTP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to configure an outbound SMTP connector on your Hub Transport server; choose the "smart host" option and give it the IP or DNS name of your ISP's mail relay.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. If anyone else needs this, here's the step by step: Exchange Management Console, Organization Configuration, Hub Transport, Send Connectors tab (right pane), Windows SBS Internet Send SERVER (right click, properties), Network tab, Select "Route mail throught he following smart hosts", Add the SMTP server that you want to forward to.